# Adjusting html tags and css styles via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My program generates the following html code. And I need to adjust it via client side scripting (jquery) in order to look exactly the code I have found extreme below. Please note I can't modify the code server-side. I need to remove ul and li tags while retaining the href links and tag names and add a css class. I also need to remove the given font size: 10px. I am not very expert in js so I need your help figuring out how to do that. I have tried some scripts including the following but it entirely removes all the li tags and their contents.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.Zend_Tag_Cloud li');
    for(var i=0; li=lis[i]; i++) {
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
</script>
```

The original code generated by my program:

```
<ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The final html code should look like the following:

```
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/136/">workout  definition</a>
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/140/">workout  plans for men</a>
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/139/">workout  program</a>
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/141/">workout  routines for beginners</a>
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/138/">workout  schedule</a>
<a class="in-the-news-bar__link" href="/content/article/tag/137/">workouts at home</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
    var $zendTagCloudLinks = $(".Zend_Tag_Cloud").find("a")
        .addClass("in-the-news-bar__link")
        .removeAttr("style");

    $zendTagCloudLinks.insertAfter(".Zend_Tag_Cloud");
    $(".Zend_Tag_Cloud").remove();
```

Comment: I agree with this. I used a similar approach with `$('.Zend_Tag_Cloud li a').removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 0):

This code converts each li to a div with the class stuff.  It uses jQuery.  Additionally, it removes the ul entirely (I believe, per your request).

```
<div class="restyle">

<ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
newHtml = "";
$("div.restyle ul.Zend_Tag_Cloud li").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").attr("style","").addClass("in-the-news-bar__link");
    newHtml += "<div class='stuff'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>";
});
$(".restyle").html(newHtml);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list links - add the class and remove the style attribute and then prepend it to the parent div that contains the list (I called that #parentDiv) - note that removing the lis t structure will cause all the a's to display in a sequence on one line rather than on separate lines - so I also added a CSS rule to cause them to display:block.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.Zend_Tag_Cloud li a').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('in-the-news-bar__link').removeAttr('style');
    $('#parentDiv').prepend($(this).parent().html());
  })
  $('.Zend_Tag_Cloud').remove();
})
```

```css
a{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv">
<ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan - i was typing said explanation as you posted your comment

Comment: Perhaps you could type the explanation and the code and not post until you have both. Save us both some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following. This solution is a bit more verbose, but doesn't require jQuery. Essentially, you put your list in a parent element (.Zend_Tag_Cloud--container) and the javascript finds the links and inserts them back into the container (removing original style and adding a class) overwriting the original ul. Depending on the context you are using this in, you will want to considering how to best namespace your class / ID names.

```js
var links = [];
var container = document.querySelector('.Zend_Tag_Cloud--container');
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.Zend_Tag_Cloud a');

for (var i=0; li=lis[i]; i++) {
  links.push(li);
}

container.innerHTML = '';

links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.style = null;
  link.className += " in-the-news-bar__link";
  container.appendChild(link);
});
```

```html
<div class="Zend_Tag_Cloud--container">
  <ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So we get a reference to the `ul` that we'll eventually replace with a document fragment. This document fragment contains the `a` we find within the `ul`. We will replace the `ul` with the fragment using jQuery's [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

The document fragment acts as a container to hold the `a` we find until we're ready to insert the new markup. Document fragments are fast and appending our items to one allow us to perform a single DOM insertion for all of the found `a`.

[end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) allows us to *"rewind"* to the previous collection as once we performed `find()` we were working with a collection of `a` and not the original collection contained in `$ul`.

```js
$( function () {

  var $ul  = $( 'ul' ),
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  $ul.find( 'a' )
     .each( function ( i, item ) {
      frag.appendChild( $( item ).addClass( 'in-the-news-bar__link' ).attr( 'style', null )[ 0 ] );
     } )
     .end()
     .replaceWith( frag );

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each()` to loop through the `a` tags, add the class, remove the `style` attribute, and append it to the document before the `.Zend_Tag_Cloud` list, then remove the list using `$.remove()`

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('in-the-news-bar__link').removeAttr('style').insertBefore('.Zend_Tag_Cloud');
});
$('.Zend_Tag_Cloud').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Zend_Tag_Cloud">
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/136/" style="font-size: 10px;">workout  definition</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/140/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  plans for men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/139/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  program</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/141/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  routines for beginners</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/138/" style="font-size: 20px;">workout  schedule</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/content/article/tag/137/" style="font-size: 20px;">workouts at home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```